# d3v4 Liquid Chart - water/oil effects - refactor

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I am working on a liquid chart module -- and I am tring to upgrade and refactor old code using d3v3 to v4

//old version 3 code
https://jsfiddle.net/5t70xz92/

//version 4
https://jsfiddle.net/ojy2v56q/

--- latest code
https://jsfiddle.net/6e1vmgaj/

---

18th June 2020
--I've tried to fix and reduce the code in this example -- although there are no visible errors - it seems to be rendering the wave in a very small block --

https://jsfiddle.net/qph352wg/1/

--

I want to decouple this from the old lib -- clean it up and make it easier to understand how this works. Take it away from the constant round circle - to make it easier for silhouettes.

```
        function loadLiquidFillGauge(elementId, value, config) {
            if (config == null) config = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings();


            const chart = d3.select(elementId[0])
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", config.width)
            .attr("height", config.height);

            const gauge = chart
            .append("g")
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)');



                    if(config.displayOverlay){
                        const imgs = chart
                                        .append("g")
                                            .attr('transform','translate(0,0)')
                                                .append("svg:image")
                                                .attr("xlink:href", config.overlayImageSrc)
                                                .attr("x", "0")
                                                .attr("y", "0")
                                                .attr("width", config.overlayImageWidth)
                                                .attr("height", config.overlayImageHeight);
                    }

                    if(config.axisLabel){
                        const axisLabel = chart
                                            .append("g")
                                                .append("text")
                                                  .attr("x", config.width/2)
                                                  .attr("y", config.height)
                                                  .attr("dy", "-4px")
                                                  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                                                  .text(config.axisLabel)
                                                  .call(wrap, (config.width / 2)-18);//add some padding

                        config.height = config.height - 40;//with the label in place reduce the height of the chart
                    }


            const randId = 'liquid_';
            var radius = Math.min(parseInt(config.width), parseInt(config.height)) / 2;

            radius = config.height / 2;

            var locationX = -parseInt(config.width) / 2;
            var locationY = parseInt(config.height) / 2 - radius;

            if (config.fillShape == "rect") {
                locationY = 0;
            }

            const fillPercent = Math.max(config.minValue, Math.min(config.maxValue, value)) / config.maxValue;

            let waveHeightScale = null;
            if (config.waveHeightScaling) {
                waveHeightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .range([0, config.waveHeight, 0])
                    .domain([0, 50, 100]);
            } else {
                waveHeightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .range([config.waveHeight, config.waveHeight])
                    .domain([0, 100]);
            }

            const textPixels = (config.textSize * radius / 2);
            const textFinalValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
            const textStartValue = config.valueCountUp ? config.minValue : textFinalValue;
            const percentText = config.displayPercent ? "%" : "";
            const circleThickness = config.circleThickness * radius;
            const circleFillGap = config.circleFillGap * radius;
            const fillCircleMargin = circleThickness + circleFillGap;
            const fillCircleRadius = radius - fillCircleMargin;
            const waveHeight = fillCircleRadius * waveHeightScale(fillPercent * 100);

            const waveLength = config.width * 2 / config.waveCount;
            const waveClipCount = 1 + config.waveCount;
            const waveClipWidth = waveLength * waveClipCount;


            // Data for building the clip wave area.
            const data = [];
            for (let i = 0; i <= 40 * waveClipCount; i++) {
                data.push({
                    x: i / (40 * waveClipCount),
                    y: (i / (40))
                });
            }

            // Scales for drawing the outer circle.
            const gaugeCircleX = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 2 * Math.PI]).domain([0, 1]);
            const gaugeCircleY = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius]).domain([0, radius]);

            // Scales for controlling the size of the clipping path.
            const waveScaleX = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, waveClipWidth]).domain([0, 1]);
            const waveScaleY = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, waveHeight]).domain([0, 1]);

            // Scales for controlling the position of the clipping path.

            // The clipping area size is the height of the fill circle + the wave height, so we position the clip wave
            // such that the it will overlap the fill circle at all when at 0%, and will totally cover the fill
            // circle at 100%.

            const waveRiseScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([(fillCircleMargin + fillCircleRadius * 2 + waveHeight), (fillCircleMargin - waveHeight)])
            .domain([0, 1]);

            const waveAnimateScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([0, waveClipWidth - fillCircleRadius * 2]) // Push the clip area one full wave then snap back.
            .domain([0, 1]);

            // Center the gauge within the parent SVG.
            const gaugeGroup = gauge.append("g")
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + locationX + ',' + locationY + ')');


            var drawOuterBlock = function() {
                // Draw the outer block.
                gaugeGroup.append("rect")
                    .attr("x", config.width / 2)
                    .attr("y", 0)
                    .attr("width", config.width)
                    .attr("height", config.height)
                    .style("fill", config.backgroundColor);
            }

            drawOuterBlock();


            // The clipping wave area.
            const clipArea = d3.area()
            .x(function(d) {
                return waveScaleX(d.x);
            })
            .y0(function(d) {
                return waveScaleY(Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * config.waveOffset * -1 + Math.PI * 2 * (1 - config.waveCount) + d.y * 2 * Math.PI));
            });

            clipArea
                .y1(function(d) {
                return (fillCircleRadius * 2 + waveHeight);
            });
            //.y1(function(d) { return (config.height - (fillCircleRadius * 2) + waveHeight); } );


            const waveGroup = gaugeGroup.append("defs")
            .append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clipWave" + randId);
            const wave = waveGroup.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("d", clipArea)
            .attr("T", 0);

            // The inner circle with the clipping wave attached.
            const fillGroup = gaugeGroup.append("g")
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clipWave" + randId + ")");

            var drawShapeWave = function(shape) {
                // Draw the wave shape.

                //console.log("config.width", config.width);
                //console.log("config.height", config.height);
                //console.log("config.margin", config.margin);

                fillGroup.append("rect")
                    .attr("x", config.width / 2 + config.margin)
                    .attr("y", config.margin)
                    .attr("width", config.width - 2 * config.margin)
                    .attr("height", config.height - 2 * config.margin)

                fillGroup
                    .style("fill", config.waveStartColor)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(config.waveColorDuration)
                    .style("fill", config.waveColor);
            }

            drawShapeWave(config.fillShape);


            // Make the wave rise. wave and waveGroup are separate so that horizontal and vertical movement can be controlled independently.
            const waveGroupXPosition = -config.width / 2;
            if (config.waveRise) {
                waveGroup.attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveGroupXPosition + ',' + waveRiseScale(0) + ')')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveGroupXPosition + ',' + waveRiseScale(fillPercent) + ')')
                    .on("start", function() {
                    wave.attr('transform', 'translate(1,0)');
                }); // This transform is necessary to get the clip wave positioned correctly when waveRise=true and waveAnimate=false. The wave will not position correctly without this, but it's not clear why this is actually necessary.
            } else {
                waveGroup.attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveGroupXPosition + ',' + waveRiseScale(fillPercent) + ')');
            }

            if (config.waveAnimate) animateWave();

            function animateWave() {
                wave.attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)');
                wave.transition()
                    .duration(config.waveAnimateTime)
                    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                    .attr('transform', `translate(${config.width},0)`)
                    .on('end', animateWave);
            }
        }
```

--- assets
[image]

[image]

=============
update 23rd June -- this is the latest d3v4 conversion

jsfiddle.net/yrkcpgj9 - I've put it into a jsfiddle - but it doesn't feel as smooth as the version 3 -jsfiddle.net/5t70xz92 -- and the variable names need to be more easier to understand - can't just have it alpha0, a -- I need it so the chart can be more configurable as it used to be -- the water just doesn't look as smooth, neither does the start up animation of configuration options –
but why did https://jsfiddle.net/qph352wg/1/ not work? why did it fail to generate the height of the wave?

Comment: I've tried to fix and reduce the code in this example -- although there are no visible errors - it seems to be rendering the wave in a very small block -- https://jsfiddle.net/qph352wg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used d3v4 to generate the following result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let width = 480;
  const $this = $('#demo_container');
  let container = d3.select($this[0]);
  let svg = container.select('svg');
  let xmin = -10;
  let xmax = 10;
  let dx = 1;
  /**
   * Height of Container decided based on ymin and ymax values
   * Container Height = (startymax - startymin) * 24px
   * So, if startymin = 0 and startymax = 20 then Container Height will be 480px
   * 
   * Other thing ymin and ymax define are the height of full and empty part of container
   * startymax = 20 means Container is total empty
   * startymin = 0 means Container has no fluid
   *
   * if, startymin = -16 means Container is 80% full
   * startymax = 4 means Container is 20% empty
   */
  let startymin = ymin = 0; // Will animate to -16
  let startymax = ymax = 20; // Will animate to 4
  /**
   * Let's we want to animate from ymin 0 to -16 means fluid height from 0% to 80%
   * and ymax 20 to 4 means 100% empty to 20% empty container
   *
   * Total duration for this animation will be 10 Seconds
   */
  let endymin = -16;
  let endymax = 4;
  let duration = 10; // Seconds
  
  // How much fluid will change per millisecond
  let changePerMillisecond = ((startymin - endymin) / (1000 * duration));
  
  /**
   * Color Scheme
   * Start RGB - 800080 - Purple
   * End RGB - 0000FF - Blue
   *
   * So, R will go from 128 to 256
   * and B will go from 128 to 0
   */
  let startR = R = 128;
  let startB = B = 128;
  let color = `#${R.toString(16)}00${B.toString(16)}`;
  
  let colorChangePerMillisecond = ((startR - 0) / (1000 * duration));
  
  let dy = 1;
  let aspect = (ymax - ymin) / (xmax - xmin);

  let grid = d3
    .range(ymin, dy, dy)
    .map(y => d3.range(xmin - dx, xmax + 2 * dx, dx).map(x => [x, y]));
  grid = grid.reduce(function(accumulated, currentValue) {
    return accumulated.concat(currentValue);
  }, []);

  var HEIGHT_OF_WAVE = 0.2; // Height
  var SPACE_BW_WAVES = 0.42; // Space between waves
  var WAVE_SPEED = 6; // Speed

  let t0 = 0;
  let pts = grid.map(xy => p(HEIGHT_OF_WAVE, SPACE_BW_WAVES, WAVE_SPEED, xy[0], xy[1], t0));
  let outline = pts.slice(pts.length - (xmax - xmin + 3));
  outline.push([xmax, ymax]);
  outline.push([xmin, ymin]);

  let xScale, yScale, rScale, pts_to_path;
  function setup() {
    svg.selectAll('*').remove();
    let height = aspect * width;
    svg.attr('height', height);
    xScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([xmin, xmax])
      .range([0, width]);
    rScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, xmax - xmin])
      .range([0, width]);
    yScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([ymin, ymax])
      .range([height, 0]);
    pts_to_path = d3
      .line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
      });

    svg
      .append("path")
      .attr('d', pts_to_path(outline))
      .attr('fill', color);
  }

  function start(t) {
    let changed = false;

    if (ymin >= -16) {
      ymin = startymin - (t * changePerMillisecond);
      changed = true;
    }

    if (ymax >= 4) {
      ymax = startymax - (t * changePerMillisecond);
      changed = true;
    }
    
    if (R > 1) {
      R = parseInt(startR - (t * colorChangePerMillisecond));
    }
    
    if (B < 254) {
      B = parseInt(startB + (t * colorChangePerMillisecond));
    }
    
    color = `#${R > 15 ? R.toString(16) : `0${R.toString(16)}`}00${B.toString(16)}`;
    
    pts = grid.map(xy => p(HEIGHT_OF_WAVE, SPACE_BW_WAVES, WAVE_SPEED, xy[0], xy[1], t / 1000));
    outline = pts.slice(grid.length - (xmax - xmin + 3));
    outline.push([xmax, ymin]);
    outline.push([xmin, ymin]);
    
    if (changed) {
      setup();
    }
    
    svg
      .selectAll("path")
      .transition()
      .duration(0)
      .attr('d', pts_to_path(outline));
    svg
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(pts)
      .transition()
      .duration(0)
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
      });
    
  }

  function p(A, alpha, beta, x0, y0, t) {
    let r = A * Math.exp(alpha * y0);
    let arg = alpha * x0 - beta * t;
    let x = x0 + r * Math.cos(arg);
    let y = y0 + r * Math.sin(arg);
    return [x, y];
  }

  setup();
  let timer = d3.timer(start);
});
```

```css
div.demo_container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
div.svg_container {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 2%;
}
svg.demo {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px lightslategray;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo_container" class="demo_container">
  <div id="water" class="svg_container">
    <svg id="water" class="demo" width=480></svg>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if it works for you?

------EDIT-------

Play with **HEIGHT_OF_WAVE**, **SPACE_BW_WAVES**, **WAVE_SPEED** variables to changes the speed, wave height, the distance between 2 waves.

Comment: yeah if we could also have a d3v4 version -- what's the difference here - what was wrong with the code I had?

Comment: I have updated the code for d3v4 version. Please check. Actually I haven't looked at your code. I will check.

Comment: We able to import the other properties from that old codebase - there was so much other stuff like changing color of the water, speed, duration, some of them were overriden in a config object - we also able to change the variable names here to from alpha0,beta0 to more understable parts -- does this create just 1 wave object? can multiple waves be added with different properties - like if we wanted to make a lava lamp -different colors/oils

Comment: like I wanted to have it - so you could render the shell - as a rect or a circle --

Comment: so on start the water is purple then turns blue -- but also rises from 0 level to where it needs to be -- like a themometer - so on start -- rather than the wave just begins -- it has those same kind of bits to it

Comment: I have updated the rise in level of water, color change.

Comment: it feels a bit jolty -- and the variable names - why we A0 and A - what are these etc..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yrkcpgj9/  - I've put it into a jsfiddle - but it doesn't feel as smooth as the version 3 -https://jsfiddle.net/5t70xz92/ -- and the variable names need to be more easier to understand - can't just have it alpha0, a -- I need it so the chart can be more configurable as it used to be -- the water just doesn't look as smooth, neither does the start up animation of configuration options

Comment: - why did this conversion fail in the wave height -- https://jsfiddle.net/qph352wg/1/

Comment: I have updated code to make it a smooth animation. Also, updated variable names to more user-readable names. I will fix the configurations for the initial animation so it will be easy to configure.

Comment: this is looking better - I think the animation of it rising could do with some easing or something - it just shunts up -- if its water and its got some weight to it - it would rush in smoother? I think also some of the durations should still in be in mili seconds e.g. animate-time=1000  --- what do these 100000 constants represent eg.. "t / 100000"

Comment: -- I've put your latest back in the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/L1svm75n/ - it seems strange the bottom of the water sits half way up - and not at the bottom of the container itself?

Comment: ^ be keen to keep it in the shell -- where the svg gets made etc.. rather than it being hard coded in the html as you got in your answer

Comment: was looking for the various improvements to take place before awarding bounty

Comment: Check my comments in the code. It might help you to understand the variables ymin and ymax. Also, how you can modify height of the container/shell based on ymin and ymax. Also, I have updated duration based on seconds. Colors and height will be changed by changing just variable duration. Hope it will help you.

Comment: No its not what I asked -

Comment: I still feel its missing older functionality -- "upgrade this old water chart from v3 to 4 -- clean up the code base - so it relies less on the old function code there -- really adapt this into something flexible -- so produce a rectangle or circle shell -- clean up the various data attributes -- earlier used defaultConfig object it bit confusing as to what should be an editable or fixed. create a working example with more details explained on how the waves are created/changed -- maybe setting up possible multiple colored waves -- if to create a lava lamp with different colored oils"

Comment: Sorry - can't award the bounty - "- rename the variables to more understandable words - eg. A0- height, Alpha2 - waterWaveHeight etc. if that's what its doing, version 3 code is lofty with a lot of different configuration parts - and uses more milisecond duration settings - so I am keen to inherit its properties/customization but having it working for v4 -- even prepare it for the option of multiple water waves behind each other to make it look like an oil lap -- different oils - colors/viscosity etc.. –"